# Nginx issues with # in Request Header

Tags: http, nginx

Some message buses and Java applications add request headers to their HTTP requests with a hash in it. Example:

```
Vendor-User-Property-#BMC: 1234
```

It seems NGINX doesn't pass this header along with the proxy_pass request. I tried to rewrite that header:

```
proxy_set_header Vendor-User-Property-BMC "$http_vendor_user_property_#bmc";
```

but unfortunately that is not a valid variable and it just adds the string value `#bmc`.

Is there a way of passing those headers unmodified with proxy_pass or any way getting the value of those headers?

Curl command used to test that:

```
curl -H "Vendor-User-Property-#BMC: 123" http://domain.tld
```

Comment: I actually had to check back with the RFCs in order to see if a # is allowed in a header name field. Turns out it is. As for your actual problem: Can you try to use `${http_vendor_user_property_#bmc}` as expansion?

Comment: Then nginx recognises the # as comment and complains about the line not being terminated by a semicolon.

Comment: Ok, last-ditch effort: `\#` instead of `#`?

Comment: Negative, now the value of the header is `\#bmc`. Thank you for looking into this!

Comment: Still interesting to know. Care to open a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's no real solution in nginx directly. I ended up putting an HAProxy in front of nginx and rewrite the HTTP header to replace the # character.

`http-request set-header Vendor-User-Property-BMC %[req.hdr("Vendor-User-Property-#BMC")]`